# How do I get the actual width, height, top, bottom, etc of a view inside a ConstraintLayout?

Tags: android-constraintlayout

When a view inside a `ConstraintLayout` is set up with `android:layout_width="0dp"` and `android:layout_height="0dp"` so that the constraints set in `app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf`and the likes are applied, methods `getWidth()`, `getMeasuredWidth()`, `getHeight()`, etc return 0. How can I get the actual width, height, etc for such a view?

Here is a sample code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/scMainFrame"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread_inside"
app:layout_optimizationLevel="chains"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
tools:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView10"
    android:layout_width="14dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="A"
    android:background="#FF0000"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/SCFrame"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/SCFrame"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView11"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView11"
    android:layout_width="14dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="B"
    android:background="#FF0000"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView10"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/SCFrame"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/SCFrame"
    />

<be.ema.sclibrary.SCConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/SCFrame"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
    android:background="#0000FF"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/textView10"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/A1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="this is A1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/A2"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/B1"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/A2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="this is A2"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/A1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/B2"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/B1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="this is B1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/A1"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/B2"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/B2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="this is B2"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/B1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/A1"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        />

</be.ema.sclibrary.SCConstraintLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

and

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    View v = findViewById(R.id.A1);
    System.out.println("A1 width=" + v.getWidth());
    System.out.println("A1 measured width=" + v.getMeasuredWidth());
    }
```

Comment: See [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3591784/getwidth-and-getheight-of-view-returns-0) for a possible solution